Would be helpful if a someone adds-up variety in this code.(I am a beginner in my coding journey, taking up python as my start)
creatures = \["\\U0001F47D", "\\U0001F9DF", "\\U0001F9DD"\]
creaname = \["alien", "zombie", "elf"\]
creapoints = \[5, 10, 15\]

print("Creatures to kill -\> ")
for crea, name in zip(creatures, creaname):
    print(f"-{crea} ({name})")

kill_one_name = input("Kill one of them | \\U0001F47D \\U0001F9DF \\U0001F9DD | : ").lower()
if kill_one_name in creaname:
    index = creaname.index(kill_one_name)
#print(index)
    print(f"Earned +{creapoints\[index\]} points for killing {creaname\[index\]}")
else:
    print("Invalid creature choice")

If someone assists me with some syntax on how to add variety to this and some ideas to improve to make it more optimal and fast.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ looks like a better forum for these sorts of questions

You might want to get rid of some of those back-slashes

it is not actually clear where you are stuck or having trouble aside from the erroneous backslashes.   what is the actual question ?  how to ask a good question:
how to ask

"some ideas to improve to make it more optimal and fast" As a first improvement I would make sure it actually works. Currently it does not, it raises a SyntaxError exception.
